# jquery - prevent execution next line code in a jquery block

Tags: jquery

firstly i want to apologize for my bad English.
in this code block:

```
    $("#div1").mouseleave(function(){
           $("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
              //To prevent hiding div2 
           });
           $("#div2").hide();
    });
```

As you see I want to prevent execution `$("#div2").hide();` if cursor entered in div2.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here,can u be more specific

Comment: Try checking whether `#div2` is the `relatedTarget` of the event: http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to delay the hiding of `div` by some milliseconds like 100, within which if the mouse enters the `div2` the cancel the hide operation

```
var div2HideTimer;
$("#div1").mouseleave(function(){
    div2HideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div2").hide();
    }, 100)
});
$("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(div2HideTimer)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question, you don't want to hide div2 if when leaving div1 the mouse immediately enters div2 or keeps being in div2.

Then you can do this :

```
// returns true if the event is over the jQuery object o
function eventIsOver(event, o) {
    if ((!o) || o==null) return false;
    var pos = o.offset();
    var ex = event.pageX;
    var ey = event.pageY;
    return (
        ex>=pos.left
        && ex<=pos.left+o.width()
        && ey>=pos.top
        && ey<pos.top+o.height()
    );
};

$("#div1").mouseleave(function(e){
           if (eventIsOver(e, $("#div2")) return;
           $("#div2").hide();
});
```

Note that depending on your exact case, you might have to do things differently. You didn't precise for example if there might be a gap between the two divs (then you'll have to deal with delays), or if one is over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this. I hope this is what you expect. Otherwise let me know what you want.

```
     $("#div1").mouseleave(function(){
       $("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
          //To prevent hiding div2 
       });
       if(!$("#div2").mouseenter()){
        $("#div2").hide();
       }
    });
```